# GIF image position animation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, animation, gif

I'm trying to change image position using JavaScript using my code but for some reason it doesn't work. Can someone explain the reason.

```js
var walk, isWaveSpawned = true;
  var walkers = [];

function start()
{
  walk = document.getElementById("walk");
      
  draw();  //Animation function
}

function draw()
{
  if(isWaveSpawned) //Generate a wave of 5 "walkers"
  {
    isWaveSpawned = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++
      walkers.push(new createWalker());
  }
      
  for(var o = 0; o < walkers.length; o++) //Add 1px to x position after each frame
  {
    walkers[o].x += walkers[o].speed;
    walkers[o].image.style.left = walkers[o].x;
    walkers[o].image.style.top = walkers[o].y;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function createWalker()
{
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 100;
    this.speed = 1;
    this.image = walk.cloneNode(false);  //Possible cause of issue
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body onload="start()">
    <img id="walk" src="https://i.imgur.com/ArYIIjU.gif">
 </body>
</html>
```

My GIF image is visible in top left corner but doesn't move.

P.S. Added a HTML/JS snippet but it outputs some errors while in my end these errors are not seen.

Comment: Can you edit your question and use the HTML/CSS/Javascript Snippet of stackoverflow instead of pasting file content for us to easily try and reproduce your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's modify the way you're cloning the gif - get rid of this line:

```
this.image = walk.cloneNode(false);
```

and insert this:

```
this.image = document.createElement("img");
```

This will create a fresh empty HTML image element.

Now assign it's **.src** property the source of your gif:

```
this.image.src=document.getElementById("walk").src;
```

and set the CSS position property to **absolute**:

```
this.image.style="position:absolute;";
```

finally add this new image element to the body using:

```
document.body.appendChild(this.image);
```

If you hit run you will still not see any movement because there's still a little fix to do!

Find this line:

```
walkers[o].image.style.left = walkers[o].x;
```

and change it to this:

```
walkers[o].image.style.left = walkers[o].x + "px";
```

```js
var walk, isWaveSpawned = true;
var walkers = [];

function start() {
  walk = document.getElementById("walk");
  draw(); //Animation function
}

function draw() {
  if (isWaveSpawned) //Generate a wave of 5 "walkers"
  {
    isWaveSpawned = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      walkers.push(new createWalker());
  }

  for (var o = 0; o < walkers.length; o++) //Add 1px to x position after each frame
  {
    walkers[o].x += walkers[o].speed;
    walkers[o].image.style.left = walkers[o].x + "px";
    walkers[o].image.style.top = walkers[o].y + "px";
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function createWalker() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 100;
  this.speed = 1;
  this.image = document.createElement("img");
  this.image.src = document.getElementById("walk").src;
  this.image.style = "position:absolute;";
  document.body.appendChild(this.image);
}

start();
```

```html
<body>
  <img id="walk" src="https://i.imgur.com/ArYIIjU.gif">
</body>
```